# Select all rows from one table as long as that id doesnt represent a null in a second table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table called **movies** that contains two columns, *id_pelicula*(movies id) and *titulo*(name of the movie), and it has the following rows.

(table movies)

[image]

Next, I have a second table called **borrowment** that contains the date of when certain movie was borrowed and the date of when the movie was returned. In case the movie has been borrowed and not returned,the return date will be NULL. The columns the table has are *id_bitacora_prestamo*(id of borrowment), *RFC*(a string that represents the person who has the movie), *id_pelicula*(movie id), *fecha_prestamo*(date it was borrowed), *fecha_retorno*(date it was returned). It has the following rows.

(table borrowment)

[image]

I want to select all of the movies that available, in other words, that is select all the rows from the table **movies** as long as their *id_pelicula*(movie id) is not in the table **borrowment**, and if the id_pelicula(movie_id) does exist in the table **borrowment**, only select if **fecha_retorno** (date returned) is NOT NULL.

Example from my table it should return the movies:

> Star wars: Episode IV - A New Hope
>
> Back to the Future

(Pardon my English)

Comment: I'm not familiar with MYsql, but the logic is more or less:
select * from movies where id_pelicula not in (select id_pelicula from borrowment where fecha_retorno is null)

Comment: post your query and let us know what issue are you facing

Answer (score 0):

Check if this one works:

```
select titulo from movies where id_pelicula in 
(select id_pelicula from borrowment where fecha_retorno is not null) or 
id_pelicula not in (select id_pelicula from borrowment);
```